# Disallowing Duplicate Elements to be Pushed Into Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a function that pushes elements from one array into an another but disallows for multiple entries of the same value. The following code does not break out of the function based on my condition, but instead pushes the matching element into the new array a second time. Furthermore, when I run the code using arguments, 1, 2, or 3, they will be pushed to the new array, but when I pass the function the number 4, I get the printed statement "number not present." Just wondering why this is happening and how to get around it. Thanks!

```
myArray = [1,2,3,4];
newOne = [];
function checkArray(num) {
    if ((num in myArray) && (num in newOne)) {
        return; 
    }
    else if (num in myArray) {
        newOne.push(num);
        console.log(newOne);
    }
    else  {
        console.log("number not present");
    }

}

checkArray(3);
checkArray(3);
checkArray(4);
```

Comment: [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) doesn't check for the content, it checks for the existence.

Comment: `in` operator check if given *index* is in the array, *index* not value. You may use `Array#indexOf` method to check if array contains given value.

Comment: Ahhhh ok, that makes sense now! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the in operator to check if an array contains a value. Use the function `indexOf()` instead. IndexOf() returns -1 if the value is not in the array, otherwise the index of the value.

The in operator checks if the index `num`is present in the array.

```
...
if ((myArray.indexOf(num) != -1) && (newOne.indexOf(num) != -1)) {
    return; 
}
else if (myArray.indexOf(num) != -1) {
    newOne.push(num);
    console.log(newOne);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`in` operator's definition is the following:

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the
>   specified object.

Arrays are indexed objects in javascript. So the command `4 in myArray`;  checks whether myArray has a property named 4, it does not check whether there is an element whose value is 4. Whereas `0 in myArray` returns true not because there is a 0 in `myArray` but `myArray` has a property named 0 . When you put an item into an array it actually holds the value in the corresponding index as a property.

```
var myArray = [2,4]; 
console.log(0 in myArray); // prints true as myArray has a field in 0th index
console.log(1 in myArray); // prints true as myArray has a field in 1st 
console.log(2 in myArray); // prints false as myArray does not have a field named 2
```

You should use `indexOf` instead if you want to check whether the value exist in an array or not.

`if(myArray.indexOf(4) > -1) // myArray contains 4`

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray = [1,2,3,4];
newOne = [];
function checkArray(num) {
    if ((myArray.indexOf(num) >= 0) && (newOne.indexOf(num) >= 0)) {
        return; 
    }
    else if (myArray.indexOf(num) >= 0) {
        newOne.push(num);
        console.log(newOne);
    }
    else  {
        console.log("number not present");
    }

}

checkArray(3);
checkArray(3);
checkArray(4);
```

I don't know if that (num in arryName) syntax is legal in javascript. When I searched it, turned up PHP. This is how I would do it in JS. Also a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/zxb49h4z/